# Grails 5 redirect to another action issue when using Spring Security

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, spring-security

I am using Grails 5.2.5 and jdk 1.8. I have implemented Spring Security v.5.0.0-RC1. Everything is working fine. When I try to login (http://subdomain.localhost:8080/login/auth) it is successfully redirecting me to secured default success url (http://subdomain.localhost:8080/dashboard/index).

After login, when I'm redirecting from secured action to another secured action using Grails redirect function then it is redirecting me to login action without subdomain in the url (eg.: http://localhost:8080/login/auth). So I have two issues here. First why redirect is behaving like this? Second why sub domain is vanishing from the URL after automatically redirect to login.

Also I want to say that `chain()` function of Grails is working fine. Below are my code snippets.

application.groovy

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.xyz.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.xyz.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.xyz.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/dashboard/index'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.failureHandler.defaultFailureUrl = '/?login_error=1'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.loginFormUrl = '/login/auth'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.afterLogoutUrl = '/login/auth'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useBasicAuth = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
        [pattern: '/',               access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/error',          access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/index',          access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/index.gsp',      access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/shutdown',       access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/assets/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/static/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/**/js/**',       access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/**/css/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/**/images/**',   access: ['permitAll']],
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
        [pattern: '/assets/**',      filters: 'none'],
        [pattern: '/static/**',      filters: 'none'],
        [pattern: '/error',      filters: 'none'],
        [pattern: '/**/js/**',       filters: 'none'],
        [pattern: '/**/css/**',      filters: 'none'],
        [pattern: '/**/images/**',   filters: 'none'],
        [pattern: '/**',             filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-basicAuthenticationFilter,-basicExceptionTranslationFilter']
]
```

UrlMapping.groovy

```
        "/"(controller: 'login', action: 'index')
```

resources.groovy

```
beans = {
    userDetailsService(CustomUserDetailService)
    baseUserPasswordEncoderListener(CustomUserPasswordEncoderListener)
}
```

CustomUserDetailService.groovy

```
class CustomUserDetailService  extends GormUserDetailsService {


UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        log.debug "User with username[${username}] trying to login"
        loadUserByUsername username, true
    }

@Transactional(readOnly=true, noRollbackFor=[IllegalArgumentException, UsernameNotFoundException])
UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username, boolean loadRoles) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        try {
            String domainPrefix = readSubDomainFromUrl()
            User user = User.findByDomainPrefixAndUsername(domainPrefix, username)
            Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = loadAuthorities(user, username, true)
            return new GrailsUser(
                    "$username",
                    user.passwd, user.loginEnabled,
                    !user.accountExpired, !user.credentialsExpired, !user.accountLocked,
                    authorities, user?.id)
        }catch(ex){

        }
    }
}
```

DemoController.groovy

```
@Secured(['ROLE_USER'])
class DemoController {


    def index(){
        redirect(action:'list', controller:'demo')
    }
    
    def list(){
       ////// code here
    }

}
```

logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <conversionRule conversionWord="clr" converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ColorConverter" />
    <conversionRule conversionWord="wex" converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.WhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(%5p) %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n%wex</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
    <logger name="com.xyz" level="debug" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.security" level="debug" />
</configuration>
```

This is spring security logs when spring security automatically redirect me to default success url after successfull login

```
2023-02-07 18:17:39.049 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /dashbaord/index
2023-02-07 18:17:39.049 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-5] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser [Username=test_username, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=2C92B25F16DACF345B99D6BD13AF0870], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]]
2023-02-07 18:17:39.049 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser [Username=test_username, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=2C92B25F16DACF345B99D6BD13AF0870], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]]
2023-02-07 18:17:39.065 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.a.h.RoleHierarchyImpl              : getReachableGrantedAuthorities() - From the roles [ROLE_ADMIN] one can reach [ROLE_ADMIN] in zero or more steps.
2023-02-07 18:17:39.065 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized filter invocation [GET /dashbaord/index] with attributes [ROLE_SUPPORT, ROLE_USER]
2023-02-07 18:17:39.065 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /dashbaord/index
```

This is the logs when I am using grails redirect action for redirect to another action

```
2023-02-07 18:21:38.114 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /demo/list
2023-02-07 18:21:38.114 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2023-02-07 18:21:38.114 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.a.h.RoleHierarchyImpl              : getReachableGrantedAuthorities() - From the roles [ROLE_ANONYMOUS] one can reach [ROLE_ANONYMOUS] in zero or more steps.
2023-02-07 18:21:38.132 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /demo/list] with attributes [ROLE_USER]
2023-02-07 18:21:38.145 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/demo/list to session
2023-02-07 18:21:38.145 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
2023-02-07 18:21:38.161 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
2023-02-07 18:21:38.161 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2023-02-07 18:21:38.161 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login/auth
2023-02-07 18:21:38.161 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2023-02-07 18:21:38.161 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.a.h.RoleHierarchyImpl              : getReachableGrantedAuthorities() - From the roles [ROLE_ANONYMOUS] one can reach [ROLE_ANONYMOUS] in zero or more steps.
2023-02-07 18:21:38.161 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized filter invocation [GET /login/auth] with attributes [permitAll]
2023-02-07 18:21:38.161 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login/auth
```

Comment: Can anybody help me on this please?

Comment: did you find the issue?